string array to normal array with double quotes in dart (flutter)
i have this
String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";

this is what i want
List array = ["folder/1.png","folder/2.png","folder/3.png"]

converting to this
List array = ["folder/1.png","folder/2.png","folder/3.png"]


where did you get [folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png] string from? i am asking since it looks like badly formatted json data (and probably this is a root of your problems) - it should be a string like ["folder/1.png","folder/2.png","folder/3.png"]

for example, do you have a case like this: `import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
final foo = ["folder/1.png","folder/2.png","folder/3.png"];
final fooStr = foo.toString();
print(fooStr);
final fooStr1 = jsonEncode(foo);
print(fooStr1);
}` ?

Are you sure that you not already have the correct way? Because array.toString() would actually be identical to your stringArray. Maybe you are just printing an actual array but simply think it's wrong

Try the following simple code snippet:
void main() {
  String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";

  stringArray = stringArray.replaceAll('[', '');
  stringArray = stringArray.replaceAll(']', '');

  var s = stringArray.split(',');
  List<String> newStringArray = [];

  for (var e in s) {
    newStringArray.add(e);
  }
  print(newStringArray);
}

It's now converted to List<String> and here's the output:

[folder/1.png, folder/2.png, folder/3.png]

Note: IDEs ignore the quotation marks, usually not displayed.
If you really want to surround that string with quotes replace the above for loop to that :
  for (var e in s) {
    var first = '"';
    var last = '"';
    e = first + e + last;
    newStringArray.add(e);
  }

Here's the output:

["folder/1.png", "folder/2.png", "folder/3.png"]

Hope it helps you.

Lets say you have this:
String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";

You can parse it with jsonDecode method, like this:
String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";
var newStr = stringArray
    .replaceAll("[", '["')
    .replaceAll(",", '","')
    .replaceAll("]", '"]');

var converted = json.decode(newStr).cast<String>().toList();

your result would be:
//["folder/1.png","folder/2.png","folder/3.png"]


════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Unexpected character (at character 2)
[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]
^


Split the String like stringArray.split(",");
Map them like this stringArray.map((file) => file.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]",""));


wrong results  flutter: ("folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png")

I just tested it on Dart Pad. Gives me a proper result. What do you mean with `` flutter: ("folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png")```

that the result m getting by print();

Well this returns an array just the way you wanted.  String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";
stringArray.split(",").map((file) => file.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]","")).forEach((t)=> print(t));

Try the following simple code snippet:
String stringArray = "[folder/1.png,folder/2.png,folder/3.png]";
String stringArray1 = stringArray.substring(1, stringArray.length - 1);
List<String> splittedArray = stringArray1.split(',');

List<String> output = splittedArray.map((e) {
  String first = '"';
  String last = '"';

  return first + e + last;
}).toList();

Hope it's help.
